# How to write a function to calculate evaluate squared error in Linear Regression?

Tags: python, function, linear-regression

I'm trying to write a function which takes feature matrix X, observed output vector y and parameter array theta as inputs and gives total cost (i.e. average squared error) as output. I am getting a syntax error in the last line (which is supposed to return the output) but I'm unable to figure out the reason.

```
def computeCost(X, y, theta):

    m = y.size  # number of training examples

    J = 0

    for i in range(m):
        error = ((theta[0])+(theta[1]*X[i])-(y[i])**2
        J = J + error


    return J*(1/(2*m))
```

Comment: Not the last line. You have an unclosed parenthesis, `(theta[0])+(theta[1]*X[i])-(y[i])**2`

Comment: Yeah it was a stupid mistake. Thanks